# SharePoint Foundation 2013 Manual Refresh List

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 custom list with thousands of data in it.  So under the Web Part Properties -> AJAX Options on the list web part, I have enabled Asynchronous Update and Show Manual Refresh Button.  Now my problem is when I click on Next Page on the list 2 times, and click on the Manual Refresh Button, it gives an empty list.  But when I click on the Next Page only once, and click the Manual Refresh Button, it just works fine.  Has anybody encountered this problem?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with the AJAX refresh in sharepoint 2013.
Try maybe doing it with javascript, add the following code to your
view or page and then just create button or make it refresh with
interval:

http://www.eliostruyf.com/ajax-refresh-item-rows-in-sharepoint-2013-view/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
// automatic refresh based on interval
function autoRefresh()
{
   window.setInterval(listViewRefresh, 2000); // 20 seconds
}

// refresh all list view web parts on the page
function listViewRefresh() {
    $('#lblMessage').text('refreshed ').fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow"); // debugging
    inplview.MyRestoreAllClvpsNavigation = MyRestoreAllClvpsNavigation;
    inplview.MyRestoreAllClvpsNavigation();
}

// Enumerate list view web parts
function MyRestoreAllClvpsNavigation()
{
    EnumCLVPs(MyCLVPRestoreNavigation);
}

// refresh referencing list view web part
function MyCLVPRestoreNavigation(clvp) {
   var strHash = ajaxNavigate.getParam("InplviewHash" + clvp.WebPartId());
   if (strHash == null)
     strHash = '';

   var strInpl = '?' + DecodeHashAsQueryString(strHash);
   var strShowInGrid = GetUrlKeyValue("ShowInGrid", true, strInpl);

   if (strShowInGrid == "True") {
     InitGridFromView(clvp.ctx.view, true);
   }
   else if (clvp.ctx.inGridMode) {
   ExitGrid(clvp.ctx.view, true);
 }
 clvp.strHash = strHash;
 clvp.fRestore = true;
 var curRootFolder = GetRootFolder2(this);

 if (curRootFolder != null)
 strInpl = SetUrlKeyValue("RootFolder", unescapeProperly(curRootFolder), true, strInpl);
 clvp.RefreshPagingEx(strInpl, true, null);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
   autoRefresh();
});
```

see to more information https://roykimsharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/12/14/sharepoint-2013-custom-list-view-web-part-refresh/